# Too many records

Tags: apex

Something I don't understand.
In this test procedure, I create 3 Qui_doit_on_couvrir__c.
When I call back them, I get 4 records. The first one in which the date is missing and value by default, then the 3 others.

Where did I scr*w up?

Records creation

```
        Qui_doit_on_couvrir__c pa1 = new Qui_doit_on_couvrir__c(Date_de_naissance__c = Date.newInstance(1980, 1, 1),Projet__c = opp.Id, Lien__c = 'Souscripteur',   Nom__c='NOM_X', Name='PRENOM_X',R_gime__c='GE',R_gime_social__c='ASS_SOCIAL');
        insert pa1;
        Qui_doit_on_couvrir__c pa2 = new Qui_doit_on_couvrir__c(Date_de_naissance__c = Date.newInstance(1982, 1, 1),Projet__c = opp.Id, Lien__c = 'Conjoint',   Nom__c='NOM_Y', Name='PRENOM_Y',R_gime__c='GE',R_gime_social__c='ASS_SOCIAL');
        insert pa2;
        Qui_doit_on_couvrir__c pa3 = new Qui_doit_on_couvrir__c(Date_de_naissance__c = Date.newInstance(2010, 1, 1),Projet__c = opp.Id, Lien__c = 'Enfant à charge',    Nom__c='NOM_Z', Name='PRENOM_Z',R_gime__c='GE',R_gime_social__c='ASS_SOCIAL');
        insert pa3;
```

Debug :

```
    personnesAssurees|[
{"Projet__c":"006AY000003p7vNYAQ","Id":"a0mAY0000000SIrYAM","Lien__c":"Souscripteur","R_gime__c":"GE","R_gime_social__c":"TNS"},  // ** record by default **
{"Projet__c":"006AY000003p7vNYAQ","Id":"a0mAY0000000SIsYAM","Lien__c":"Souscripteur","Date_de_naissance__c":"1980-01-01T00:00:00.000Z","R_gime__c":"GE","R_gime_social__c":"ASS_SOCIAL"},
{"Projet__c":"006AY000003p7vNYAQ","Id":"a0mAY0000000SItYAM","Lien__c":"Conjoint","Date_de_naissance__c":"1982-01-01T00:00:00.000Z","R_gime__c":"GE","R_gime_social__c":"ASS_SOCIAL"},
{"Projet__c":"006AY000003p7vNYAQ","Id":"a0mAY0000000SIuYAM","Lien__c":"Enfant à charge","Date_de_naissance__c":"2010-01-01T00:00:00.000Z","R_gime__c":"GE","R_gime_social__c":"ASS_SOCIAL"}
```

Test :

```
@IsTest
public class ApiviaListProductsTest {
    @isTest
    static void testApiviaListProducts() {
        // Création du compte
        Account testAccount = new Account(LastName = 'Test',FirstName = 'Account', PersonMailingPostalCode = '75001', RecordTypeId = '01209000000iwzLAAQ');
        insert testAccount;
        
        // Création du projet
        Opportunity opp = new Opportunity(AccountId = testAccount.Id, CloseDate = Date.today(), Name = 'Test Opp', RecordTypeId = '012IV0000005vfB', Stagename = 'Je télécharge mes pièces');
        insert opp;
        
        Qui_doit_on_couvrir__c pa1 = new Qui_doit_on_couvrir__c(Date_de_naissance__c = Date.newInstance(1980, 1, 1),Projet__c = opp.Id, Lien__c = 'Souscripteur',   Nom__c='NOM_X', Name='PRENOM_X',R_gime__c='GE',R_gime_social__c='ASS_SOCIAL');
        insert pa1;
        Qui_doit_on_couvrir__c pa2 = new Qui_doit_on_couvrir__c(Date_de_naissance__c = Date.newInstance(1982, 1, 1),Projet__c = opp.Id, Lien__c = 'Conjoint',   Nom__c='NOM_Y', Name='PRENOM_Y',R_gime__c='GE',R_gime_social__c='ASS_SOCIAL');
        insert pa2;
        Qui_doit_on_couvrir__c pa3 = new Qui_doit_on_couvrir__c(Date_de_naissance__c = Date.newInstance(2010, 1, 1),Projet__c = opp.Id, Lien__c = 'Enfant à charge',    Nom__c='NOM_Z', Name='PRENOM_Z',R_gime__c='GE',R_gime_social__c='ASS_SOCIAL');
        insert pa3;
        system.debug(pa1);
        system.debug(pa2);
        system.debug(pa3);
        
        // Création d'un mock pour la classe HttpCalloutMock
        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new MyHttpCalloutMock());
    
        system.debug(opp.Id);
        // Appel de la méthode à tester
        ApiviaListProducts.ApiviaListProducts(new List<String>{opp.Id});
    
        // Vérification des résultats
        List<Quote> quotes = [SELECT Name, Cout_total__c, Produit__r.ProductCode FROM Quote WHERE OpportunityId = :opp.Id];
        System.assertEquals(3, quotes.size());
        System.assertEquals('Apivia VITAMM3 SOLO', quotes[0].Name);
        System.assertEquals(1400.0, quotes[0].Cout_total__c);
        System.assertEquals('VITAMM3_SOLO', quotes[0].Produit__r.ProductCode);
        System.assertEquals('Apivia VITAMM3 CONJOINT', quotes[1].Name);
        System.assertEquals(1300.0, quotes[1].Cout_total__c);
        System.assertEquals('VITAMM3_CONJOINT', quotes[1].Produit__r.ProductCode);
        System.assertEquals('Apivia VITAMM3 AUTRE', quotes[2].Name);
        System.assertEquals(1100.0, quotes[2].Cout_total__c);
        System.assertEquals('VITAMM3_AUTRE', quotes[2].Produit__r.ProductCode);
    }
    
    // Classe de mock pour la méthode HttpCalloutMock
    private class MyHttpCalloutMock implements HttpCalloutMock {
        public HttpResponse respond(HttpRequest req) {
            HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
            res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            res.setBody('{"status":"success","list":{"VITAMM3":{"tarifs_total":{"SOLO":100.0,"SOLO_prorata":50.0,"CONJOINT":100.0,"CONJOINT_prorata":50.0,"AUTRE":100.0,"AUTRE_prorata":50.0}}}}');
            res.setStatusCode(200);
            return res;
        }
    }
}
```

called method :

```
public with sharing class ApiviaListProducts {
    
    private static List<Opportunity> getProjectAndAssuredUser(List<String> projectId) {
        Boolean valide = true;

        List<Opportunity> opp = [SELECT account.PersonMailingPostalCode, (SELECT Id,  Lien__c, Date_de_naissance__c, R_gime__c, R_gime_social__c FROM Personne_assure__r) FROM Opportunity WHERE Id = :projectId];
        if(opp != null){ 
            Boolean isSouscripteur = false;
            Boolean allUserAreOk = true;

            // recuperation de l'opportunité
            Opportunity myOpp = opp.get(0);

            // l'opportunité contient elle le code postal
            if(myOpp.account.PersonMailingPostalCode != null) {

                // l'opportunité contient elle des utilisateur dont au moins 1 Souscripteur
                List<Qui_doit_on_couvrir__c> personnesAssurees = myOpp.Personne_assure__r;
                
                if(personnesAssurees != null) {
                    
                    // on parcours les enregistrement pour voir si un souscripteur existe
                    for(Qui_doit_on_couvrir__c pa : personnesAssurees){ 
                        system.debug('pa :' + pa);
                        if(pa.Lien__c == 'Souscripteur') {
                            isSouscripteur = true;
                        }
                        if(pa.Date_de_naissance__c == null || pa.Lien__c == null || pa.R_gime__c == null || pa.R_gime_social__c == null) {
                            allUserAreOk = false;
                            system.debug('il manque une info sur un assuré : ' + pa);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            if(!isSouscripteur || !allUserAreOk) {
                opp = null;
            }
        } else {
            return null;
        }
        return opp;
    }
    
    
    
    @InvocableMethod
    public static void ApiviaListProducts(List<String> projectId) {
        if(projectId != null) { 
            // recupération des données du projet actuel et de l'utilisateur

            List<Opportunity> opp = getProjectAndAssuredUser(projectId);        
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible that you have a trigger (or other automation) on `Opportunity` that creates a  `Qui_doit_on_couvrir__c` record when a new Opportunity is inserted?

Comment: Ho yes, exactly, One user is created when we create an opportunity. Is it possible to simulatate this trigger?

Comment: If you DML the Opportunity and a `Qui_doit_on_couvrir__c` is created as a side effect, then you can either ignore, adjust your asserts, or move to the UnitOfWork and Selector patterns so you can mock out any DML of objects in the testmethod

Comment: Ok thanks. I test that. 
many thanks. :)